# Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault - No such file or directory

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb

I am running gdb to debug a program with a segmentation fault error. When I build my app and run

```
gdb ./app
```

I get the following output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcpy_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-avx2.S:611
611     ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-avx2.S: No such file or directory.
```

Running `bt` gives,

```
#0  __strcpy_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-avx2.S:611
```

I am not sure about missing file for gdb.

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: Use a stace to see which call to `strcpy()` is getting the error. Then you should be able to check the values of the arguments to see which is invalid.

Comment: I think "No such file or directory" just means it can't show the source code of `strcpy`. You can ignore that.

Comment: Guessing there's a null pointer or copying to a string literal involved. The missing file isn't an issue, you can find your code in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure about missing file for gdb.

The missing file is part of GLIBC source, which you can install.

However, a crash inside `strcpy` implementation ~always means that you called that function with invalid parameters (e.g. a `NULL` pointer, an invalid source or destination, a non-writable destination, etc. etc.).

Therefore, you should use `where` GDB command to check where the call to `strcpy` came from, and examine the *caller* (which is likely to be in your own code).